How to disable PSR12 statement bracket in same line?
I am currently working on a standard formatting configuration for my PHP project. I want to use the PSR-12 rules, but I prefer to disable the rule that forces the opening curly brace to be on the same line as the statement.
For example:
if (true) { // Wrong
} 

if (true)
{ // Correct
}

I would like to apply this to all types of statements, including classes, functions, if, else, and others. How can I achieve this?
This is my phpcs.xml now:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Standard">


    <rule ref="PSR12" />
    
    <rule ref="Generic.Formatting.MultipleStatementAlignment" />
    <rule ref="Generic.Formatting.SpaceAfterCast" />
    <rule ref="Generic.Arrays.DisallowLongArraySyntax" />

    <exclude-pattern>vendor/*</exclude-pattern>
</ruleset>

